# reboot multiple and very specific pods using a single syntax

Tags: kubectl, kubernetes-pod

```
root@x:~# kubectl get pods -A -o wide| grep nic
a      k-e-f-v1-k-e-nic-s-r8tjn           1/1     Running     1          5d11h   192.168.99.1     master.k                <none>           <none>
a      k-e-f-v1-k-e-nic-s-w6tk8           1/1     Running     0          5d11h   192.168.99.231   e-519-19121100100009   <none>           <none>
a      k-e-f-v1-k-e-nic-s-z8pmq           1/1     Running     0          5d11h   192.168.99.127   e-519-19121100100008   <none>           <none>
```

want to restart all the pods other than the master in namespace a from the above result.
Is there can be a single syntax to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do those pods have any specific labels that can be used for identifying them ? If they are not labelled so far, I would recommend you to do that as `grep`-ing for a specific string in their names is neither very convinient nor elegant solution. And for sure you cannot select pods that contain a specific string in their name with pure `kubectl` command, without using an external tool like `grep`.

As to selecting all pods (either in a specific `--namespace` or in `--all-namespaces`), running on all nodes except the specific one, it can be done quite easily by using **negation** in `--field-selector`:

The following **command** will list `Pods` from `--all-namespaces`, running on any node other than `master`. Additionally it will list only `Pods` that are labelled with the key `app` and the value `nginx`:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeName!=master --selector=app=nginx
```

If you want to delete such `Pods`, run:

```
kubectl delete pods --all-namespaces --field-selector spec.nodeName!=master --selector=app=nginx
```

As you may know, **deletion** of `Pods` is basically the same as **restarting/rebooting** them. If those `Pods` are managed e.g. by a `Deployment` they will be simply recreated after deletion.

If you really have to use `grep` to search for a specific string in names of your `Pods`, you can use a fairly simple script to delete such specific `Pods`:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o name --field-selector spec.nodeName!=master | grep nic | xargs kubectl delete
```

But as you can see, the above command is way more complicated than a single `kubectl delete` that uses a `--selector` flag to filter out only `Pods` with specific labels.  This one uses `grep`, `xargs`, two pipes and two separate `kubectl` command runs.